# Instantiate class with no constructor and populate get-only members

Tags: c#

In order to display a `Geopath` on a `MapControl` on UWP I need to pass the `Geopath` to the `MapControl` through a metadata class called `MapRoute`.

I can't instantiate the `MapRoute` class for some reason. When I try:

```
var route = new MapRoute();
```

IntelliSense says this:

`MapRoute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

How can I instantiate this class? How to populate its `get`-only members?
If I can't, how does the API/Runtime do it?

[image]

Comment: Which member are you talking about?

Comment: I need to put a `Geopath` into `MapRoute`'s `Path` property and pass the `MapRoute` object to `MapControl` to display a route on a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API underlying Library have private or protected member that it has access to.

A [MapRouteFinderResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maproutefinderresult) is returned when you call the methods of the [MapRouteFinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maproutefinder) class.

How according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maproute):

> A [MapRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maproute) object is returned through the [Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maproutefinderresult#Windows_Services_Maps_MapRouteFinderResult_Route) property of the
>   MapRouteFinderResult when you call the methods of the MapRouteFinder
>   class. To display a MapRoute on a MapControl, construct a MapRouteView
>   with the MapRoute and add the MapRouteView to the Routes collection of
>   the MapControl. Your Universal Windows app must be authenticated
>   before it can use the MapControl and map services in the
>   Windows.Services.Maps namespace. To authenticate your app, you must
>   specify a maps authentication key.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For future readers: To draw routes on a `MapControl` use the `MapElements` property and the `MapPolyline` class.